# Ensure that input value is string of alphabets in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, restrict

I'm developing a reactjs application and I want that my user must enter only alphabets in an input field.
Here is my code.

```
<input value= {this.state.val} onChange = {this.handleVal}/>


handleVal = (e)=>{
      this.setState({
      val:e.target.value
      })
}


state = {
  val:''
}
```

My component has lot of code but i entered only the relevant.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Regular expression test, and only update the input state if it passes the test on the onChange handler

```
/^[a-zA-Z]*$/
```

Usage in your onChange handler

```
  handleVal = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const regMatch = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(value);

    if (regMatch) {
        this.setState({
            val: value
        })
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onKeyPress method it will avoid typing anything else from alphabets.

```
 <input placeholder="Enter Alphabets only" onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress} onChange={this.onChange} />

onKeyPress = (event) => {
   if((event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && 
     event.charCode < 123)){
        return true;
   }
      return false;
}

onChange =  (e) => {
  console.log('_________', e.target.value);
  this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
  })
}
```